# Copy links from image src as a text

Tags: jquery

I have a list where each `li` has some image inside and I'm trying to copy each `img src=` as plain text to `.someDiv`

HTML

```
<ul class="someList">
  <li><a href=""><img src="/linktopicture1.jpg" class="someImage"></a></li>
  <li><a href=""><img src="/linktopicture2.jpg" class="someImage"></a></li>
  <li><a href=""><img src="/linktopicture3.jpg" class="someImage"></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="someDiv">
  <!-- those source links should be written here like this:
  /linktopicture1.jpg
  /linktopicture2.jpg
  /linktopicture3.jpg 
  -->
</div>
```

I've tried something like this, but it's not right:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.someList li').each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);

     // Get src attribute from img
     var url = $this.find('.someImage').first().attr('src');

     // Set href attribute on a
     $this.find('.someDiv').first().attr(url);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in statement

```
 $this.find('.someDiv').first().attr(url);
```

`.someDiv` is not child of current element i.e. `this` thus above code will not work.

instead use

```
$('.someDiv').append(url);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.someList li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var url = $this.find('.someImage').attr('src');
    //Set anchor href
    $this.find('a').attr('href', url);
    $('.someDiv').append(url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="someList">
  <li>
    <a href=""><img src="/linktopicture1.jpg" class="someImage"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><img src="/linktopicture2.jpg" class="someImage"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><img src="/linktopicture3.jpg" class="someImage"></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="someDiv">
</div>
```